# 'E: Unable to locate package hydra' In termux

Tags: linux, termux, hydra

I started to use termux in my cellphone, and looking for information I find that I can install hydra in it.
However, when I use the comand

```
pkg install hydra
```

All I get is an error message as you can see in the title. I've tried to update and upgrade the system several times, but I'm still getting the same error.

So, I wonder... is there a chance that this library has another name? (I said it because I've seen other comments with the same error in other posts)

So please, can you help me to solve this?
Additionaly, I upload 2 pictures: the first one with the error message I get. The second one is some information that I think I might help (when I seach for that command 'hydra', it seems to be not found).

Thanks in advance.

[image: The error I get]

[image: Search hydra]

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux tools/apps. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Also, please do not post text output as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/FAQ#Where_are_Metasploit_and_Hydra_packages) Hydra package has been removed from Termux repositories and no longer installable.